# Converting a hex file into a bmp

Tags: vhdl, bmp, image-conversion

I am testing an electronic chip (software simulated) with an openly available library (as in "open source"). The test for this chip (available with the library) has a hex file as an input ..... This hex file is supposedly a dump of an actual bmp.

As a tester, I follow the "Trust but verify" motto :) so I want to see whether this dump is actually a correct image i.e. if this hex dump is correct, then I must be able to convert this back into a bmp. Is there such a tool/script available anywhere ?

Thanks in advance and appreciate the help.

Comment: (in the assumptions you're working on a unix system) could you post the output of the command 'file the_hex_file' and if possible 'head the_hex_file'.  Gimp has quite some good conversion funtions.

Answer (score 0):

I have one done simmilar things while implementing an image filter algorithm. I used [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) to read in the HEX Data as a matrix. Then use the `imshow(<matrix>)`function to display the data as an image. There was no need to fiddle around with BMP headers.

I you do not have Matlab, or are not willing to pay for it, then you can try [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/), which is an free and open source alternative. I have not yet used it extensively but it is said, that Scilab ist (for the most part) compatible with the Matlab syntax.