# How are raw (hex) bitmap data created and is it possible to view them without a different program?

Tags: c, arduino

Recently I started to work with the [M5 Stacks Core 2](https://docs.m5stack.com/en/core/core2) and wondered how they displayed images onto the screen. Using an [example given for Arduino](https://github.com/m5stack/M5-ProductExampleCodes/tree/master/Core/M5Core2/Arduino/Core2_Factory_test), I see that the project file contains many '.c' files containing a `const unsigned char` followed by a series of hex values. Here is an example of one of those files:

```
const unsigned char image_DigNumber_0000_0[504] = { 
0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x16, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xc7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1e, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
0xff, 0xff, 0x21, 0x11, 0x11, 0x12, 0x34, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x42, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1a, 0xf5, 0x4f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x76, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1c, 0xff, 0x74, 
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x7f, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1f, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x4c, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0x77, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1f, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x6f, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x11, 
0x11, 0x1f, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1f, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1f, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 
0x7f, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x5f, 0xff, 0xfa, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xf5, 0x11, 0x11, 0x5f, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x9f, 0xff, 0xf5, 0x11, 0x11, 0x5f, 0xff, 0xf7, 
0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0xcf, 0xff, 0xf5, 0x11, 0x11, 0x5f, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0xcf, 0xff, 0xf5, 0x11, 0x11, 0x6f, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0xcf, 0xff, 0xf5, 0x11, 
0x11, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0xcf, 0xff, 0xf5, 0x11, 0x11, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xf3, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xf2, 0x11, 0x11, 0x7f, 0xfd, 0x41, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 
0x17, 0xff, 0xf1, 0x11, 0x11, 0x2f, 0xd2, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x6f, 0xc1, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x13, 0x31, 0x11, 0x11, 0x56, 0x11, 0x11, 
0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0xef, 0x91, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x13, 0xdf, 0x31, 0x11, 0x11, 0xff, 0xfa, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x4f, 0xff, 0x71, 0x11, 
0x13, 0xff, 0xff, 0x91, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x13, 0xff, 0xff, 0x71, 0x11, 0x15, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc1, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0xff, 0x71, 0x11, 0x15, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc1, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 
0xff, 0xff, 0x71, 0x11, 0x15, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc1, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0xff, 0x51, 0x11, 0x15, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc1, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0xff, 0x51, 0x11, 0x15, 0xff, 0xff, 0xb1, 
0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0xff, 0x51, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0xff, 0x71, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1c, 0xff, 0xff, 0x51, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0xff, 0x71, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1c, 0xff, 0xff, 0x41, 0x11, 
0x17, 0xff, 0xff, 0x71, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1c, 0xff, 0xff, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0xff, 0x71, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1c, 0xff, 0xff, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0xff, 0x61, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x1d, 
0xff, 0xff, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0xf7, 0x7c, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0x47, 0xff, 0xff, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 0xff, 0x77, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf4, 0x6f, 0xfc, 0x11, 0x11, 0x17, 0xfa, 0x7f, 0xff, 
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x44, 0xf7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x14, 0x97, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf4, 0x31, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x2f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 
0x11, 0x19, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xd7, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 
};
```

It is called in the main code like this:

```
DisClockbuff.drawColorBitmap(posx[1],26,24,42,
                        DigNumber[ sytState.Rtctime.Hours % 10 ],
                        0xff9c00,
                        0x1a1100);
```

My question is how did they create this bitmap images and gather its hex values. Additionally, how would I be able to view these individual bitmap images using the hex values. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to watch Ben Eater's series on the "Worst Video Card" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqY3FMuMuRo) It will give you some insights into how an image is represented as binary data. Watch from minute 15:00 from the previous link.

It is possible to convert hex to bmp by following this description: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oj1I55Amrsk

If you are patient you could do it manually here: https://hexed.it  based on those rules, however, this is suitable for creating a nice C++ or Matlab algorithm, as it has been previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505871/converting-a-hex-file-into-a-bmp)

Answer (score 0):

> how did they create this bitmap images and gather its hex values?

How the image can be created depend on the hardware of the display, more specifically the display driver chip used by the display module. You would have to know the display driver (i.e. reading the data sheet of the display driver) and create library, fonts for using the chip.

I don't know what display M5 Stacks is using, but I have a blog talk about how to create a display library for using a LCD display commonly-known as [Nokia 5110 display](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2017/11/how-to-use-lcd-5110-pcd-8544-with-arduino/) which uses a display chip called PCD 8544, the blog should give you some insight on how a bitmap image can be created for that particular display chip.

> how would I be able to view these individual bitmap images using the hex values?

The answer is maybe. If you know the columns and the rows, and align your data accordingly, you might be able to see roughly the image to be displayed. For example, this is bitmap image of Adafruit's logo for its SSD1306 lcd (which is a 128x64 pixels oled display), when align the data this way, you could vaguely see the star fruit logo from far direct from this data structure, because the data bit (0 or 1) is directly related to the pixel to be displayed on the screen in this case. This however might not be possible, depend on how data is structured (e.g. some display divided the display into page, and within each page, each data byte represent a vertical column on the display).

```
static const unsigned char PROGMEM logo_bmp[] =
{ 0b00000000, 0b11000000,
  0b00000001, 0b11000000,
  0b00000001, 0b11000000,
  0b00000011, 0b11100000,
  0b11110011, 0b11100000,
  0b11111110, 0b11111000,
  0b01111110, 0b11111111,
  0b00110011, 0b10011111,
  0b00011111, 0b11111100,
  0b00001101, 0b01110000,
  0b00011011, 0b10100000,
  0b00111111, 0b11100000,
  0b00111111, 0b11110000,
  0b01111100, 0b11110000,
  0b01110000, 0b01110000,
  0b00000000, 0b00110000 };
```